# Jenkins plugin ssh-agent showing "ERROR: Failed to run ssh-add"

Tags: jenkins, ssh-agent

I getting error "ERROR: Failed to run ssh-add"
I am trying to ssh into remote machine so

SSH credential are set 
[image: pic1]
Pipeline script is calling ssh-agent 
[image: pic2]
On executing the job I get error below
[image: pic3]

I have tried this reported bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50181 but it is not working and bug has been already resolved in latest version 1.17 which i have now.
Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 15):

This is just a wild guess since this could have different reasons.

But I just had this error, and my problem was that when I created the credential in Jenkins I forgot to add a `linebreak` at the end of the input.

```
...
...<all the usual content>...
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----<linebreak needed here>
```

Comment: This also was the problem in my case.

Comment: I've also faced with this issue! Thanks!

Comment: This has not solved it for me which type of key was used? for example RSA

Comment: Thank you so much, after hours looking around the linebreak did solve the issue for me too.

Comment: Wow thank you so much.  I swapped out some keys and everything stopped working.  All our releases broken.  Couldnt figure this out.  Post your cashapp so i can send you some money lol

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I put the SSH **public** key into the Jenkins credential instead of properly putting the **private** key.

Note that the private key is the long one that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
... lots of unreadable random characters for many lines ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Same issue in my end.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I didn't put they private key's passphrase into Jenkins.

I thought the key didn't have a passphrase because I wasn't having to enter it when using the key manually. It turns out my local keyring was automatically taking care of this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after copying the `credentials.xml` file from an old installation to a new one. The key appears to be stored in a hashed format in the `credentials.xml` file and may be the hash is unique based on the version of jenkins. I just had to find the private key on my system and then paste it in the UI along with the additional line break as suggested by @peedee

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to use OpenSSH key format in Jenkins credentials - remote session always fails with *ERROR: Failed to run ssh-add*.

The solution was to provide a PEM key generated with *-m PEM* flag. So the private key format should be: "*-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----*" instead of "*-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----*" etc.