# Jenkins SSH Agent Plugin shows empty drop down in Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ssh-agent

I am using SSH Agent Plugin version 1.17 with Jenkins version 2.190.3

When I create credentials using 
Jenkins -> Credentials -> System -> Global credentials (unrestricted) -> Add Credentials

But when I create jenkins job type Freestyle project, I don't see credentials in ssh agent drop down.

[image]
Please advise what I am missing

Ref:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029470091-How-to-use-the-SSH-Agent-Plugin

[Jenkins plugin ssh-agent showing "ERROR: Failed to run ssh-add"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605045/jenkins-plugin-ssh-agent-showing-error-failed-to-run-ssh-add)

**Update:**

Issue is open for credentials (username/password) https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59807
but good thing is that it works with private key :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select **Kind** as `SSH Username with private key` to be able to specific use credentials in ssh agent:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah! you need to add the SSH credentials first before connecting.

Comment: Thanks Sers, just notice it is existing issue with username/password but it works with private key https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59807